# Custom metrics sent datadog using micrometer DatadogRegistry not showing up in Datadog metric summary

Tags: java, spring-boot, datadog, micrometer

I want to send custom metrics using io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry to datadog. Below is the code snippet of the method where I am emitting metrics to Datadog.

```
@Override
    public void emitMetrices(Map<String, String> dataPoints) {
        try {
            logger.info("inside emitMetrices from monitoring service with enableCustomMetrics: {}",
                    enableCustomMetrics);
            if (!isEnabled()) {
                logger.warn("Metrics are diabled");
                return;
            }

            // user supplied metrics
            Set<Tag> tags = new LinkedHashSet<Tag>();
            Set<Entry<String, String>> dataPointEntries = dataPoints.entrySet();
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : dataPointEntries) {
                String key = entry.getKey() == null ? MetricConstants.UNKNOWN_TEXT : entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue() == null ? MetricConstants.UNKNOWN_TEXT : entry.getValue();
                tags.add(new ImmutableTag(key, value));
            }

            String tenantMoniker = MetricConstants.UNKNOWN_TEXT;
            String stackName = MetricConstants.UNKNOWN_TEXT;

            TenantDescriptor tenant = TenantContextHolder.get();
            if (tenant != null) {
                tenantMoniker = tenant.getTenantMoniker();
                stackName = tenant.getTierName();
            } else {
                logger.warn("Tenant is not available");
            }

            Tag tenantTag = new ImmutableTag(MetricConstants.TENANT_MONIKER, tenantMoniker);
            Tag stackNameTag = new ImmutableTag(MetricConstants.STACK_NAME, stackName);
            Tag serviceNameTag = new ImmutableTag(MetricConstants.SERVICE_NAME, serviceName);

            tags.add(tenantTag);
            tags.add(stackNameTag);
            tags.add(serviceNameTag);

            logger.info("sending metric to datadog");
            Counter counter = meterRegistry.counter(METRIC_NAME, tags);
            counter.increment();

            logger.info("metric sent successfully: {}", METRIC_NAME);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error publishing metrics", e);
        }

    }
```

I am able to see logs "metric sent successfully" with no error but this custom metric is not showing up in Datadog UI under metrics summary. Am I missing anything?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem. Micrometer claims that metrics are successfully sent but I cannot see them in DataDog.

Comment: Sorry for replying late here. I was using the meter filter unknowing which just denies sending the metrics when the name of the metric doesn't match the pattern. I was giving the different metric name which was not matching the pattern.           
registry.config().meterFilter(
    MeterFilter.denyUnless(id -> PatternMatchUtils.simpleMatch("metric_pattern", id.getName())));

Answer (score 0):

The MeterRegistry already has implemented how to send custom metrics (posting to DataDog) See the code https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-datadog/src/main/java/io/micrometer/datadog/DatadogMeterRegistry.java#L133

It appears like you are trying to add common tags to each metric. Perhaps you shouldn't implement your own DataDog registry, and instead use the provided one to send the metrics and set the common tags via config:

```
registry.config().commonTags(Arrays.asList(
  Tag.of(MetricConstants.TENANT_MONIKER, tenant.getTenantMoniker()), 
  Tag.of(MetricConstants.STACK_NAME, stackName)
));
```

Comment: registry.config().meterFilter(
    MeterFilter.denyUnless(id -> PatternMatchUtils.simpleMatch("metric name", id.getName())));